# How to use mysqli in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, pdo

I need to know how to use mysqli in WordPress. I don't want to use wpdb or PDO any thing else. Actually the issue is there are 190+ queries written in mysql and i need to convert them to mysqli, i know the better solution is to go with wpdb. But it would be more time taking. So i just i need to know how to use mysqli in WordPress. I have googled it lot but every where every one is suggesting to use wpdb, but i want to stick with mysqli.

So right now my code is e.g :

```
mysql_query("select * from `wp_users`);
```

if I write in mysqli it would be

```
mysqli_query($HOW_TO_GIVE_CONNECTION_HERE, "select * from `wp_users`);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What underlying reason is it better for you to establish two (or more) database connections instead of one? Is the time of you reading one page of documentation less than the time of asking this question and waiting on answers that aren't as good as what you have available? At the end of the day, the `$wpdb` object is just a wrapper that uses the mysqli methods anyway. So it seems like you are just going "I don't care, I want to use this regardless of what is best for efficiency or best for security." And if that's the case, so be it - but there is a reason everyone is suggesting you use wpdb.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. But don't know why my client want to look it like that.  He have a short budget and don't want to do every thing in wpdb

Comment: If someone was on a time-sensitive budget that required me to provide the fastest solution, I would think using the pre-built database class provided to me would be much faster than finding out how to essentially  write custom code that ultimately recreates the wheel. `$wpdb->query` is essentially the same as running `mysqli_query` at the end of the day. This already works, I think you're going to spend far more time trying to figure out how to circumvent what already exists than reading the 4 paragraphs of documentation on using wpdb :p

Answer (score 1):

You're right to want to learn to use MySQL with php from the ground up. You can use libraries and shortcuts and optimizations when you appreciate how and when to use them. Here's an example of how straightforward basic msqli can be:

```
        <?php
                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                      {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }

                    // Perform queries
                    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
                    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age)
                    VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

                    mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

If you're comfortable with objects this is a good tutorial:
http://codular.com/php-mysqli
but this one is a bit fuller and will give you a very good grounding in PHP-MySQL:
https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17

Comment: What if OP needs to run one query using mysqli in fileA but another mysqli query in fileB? Is he going to open 2 different connections? What if he wants to run one query in page.php and another in header.php and another in a plugin? 3 connections?

Comment: Can we make it more generalize like to pick connecion from wp-config?