# mysqli_connect not defined in wordpress 4.8.1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I just upgraded to PHP7 and WordPress 4.8.1 and am encountering fatal errors because mysql_connect has been deprecated and mysqli_connect is not defined anywhere in the code base.

I had a version of php-mysqli.dll that I updated with a "newer" version in the php/ext folder, but neither seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mysqli in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092701/how-to-use-mysqli-in-wordpress)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281467/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect Does this help at all? Perhaps a server configuration thing you might need to change.